# Heroku: Dump Postgres database into local SQLite3 database for Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite, dump

Is there way to dump heroku postgres database and import the data into my local SQLite database?

I tried using https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db and heroku db:pull with no success. I am developing on Windows 7.

Comment: Are you only after the data? You could export data as csv from Postgres and import data as csv to SQLite3.

Comment: Figuring out how to use Postgres in Dev is also probably a worthwhile experiment - it runs natively on Windows http://www.postgresql.org/download/.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<del>Please read through</del>

<del>https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export</del>

<del>and follow those to export.</del>

Though the above link can be used to export alone, it does not have solution for the entire process. So you can look on the similar question and its solution

[Copy a heroku postgres db to a local sqlite db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122116/copy-a-heroku-postgres-db-to-a-local-sqlite-db)

Comment: This is one of my favorites Heroku blog posts.

Comment: Well I did install Postgres. It is gonna be a lesson not to sidestep the problems. Thank you all.

Comment: The question is about exporting a pgsql dumpfile and importing it on sqlite. This documentation page has nothing to do with that, it just shows how to do the first part... the puzzling part is the second one ! I don't understand why this answer is accepted :( !