# Copy a heroku postgres db to a local sqlite db

Tags: sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I want to copy my heroku production db (postgres) to my development (sqlite).

Copying a postgres db into another postgres db is easy using `heroku pg:pull`. Does anyone know how to use this command to **copy postgres into sqlite**?

[Heroku docs on pg:pull](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) do not say how to use different types of dbs. [This old article](http://www.scholarslab.org/research-and-development/synchronizing-development-databases/) implied that it used to be possible. Setting up a local postgres db is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: "Setting up a local postgres db is something I'd like to avoid". Why? It's trivial, and doing dev in SQLite then production ops in PostgreSQL is practically guaranteed to bite you with a nasty error at some point - you need to at minimum *test* with Pg.

Comment: I develop on a laptop with a 16GB SSD, so I prefer SQLite because each database is contained in one file which is easy to move to a HDD to free up disk space when I'm done with a project. Doing that kind of thing with PostgreSQL (and setting it up in the first place, IMO) is a pain in the neck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need do a `pg_restore` locally then dump the data using the `-a` option to dump data only.

It should look something like this:

1. Download a data dump.

   ```
   heroku addons:add pgbackups
   heroku pgbackups:capture
   curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
   ```
2. Create a temporary database.

   ```
   sudo -u postgres createdb tempdb
   ```
3. Restore the dump to your temporary database.

   ```
   sudo -u postgres pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d tempdb latest.dump
   ```
4. Dump the data in the correct format.

   ```
   sudo -u postgres pg_dump --inserts -a -b tempdb > data.sql
   ```
5. Read dump in sqlite3.

   ```
   sqlite3
   > .read data.sql
   ```

This is an approximate solution.  You will most likely need to make some small adjustments.

I agree with [Craig Ringer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398670/craig-ringer) that it might be worth getting postgres running locally.  Hopefully this process will do the trick though!

Comment: Why dump it to a temporary database first?

Comment: Not sure, feel free to edit. It's been a year since I've looked at this. :)

Comment: step 2 is now "sudo -u _postgres createdb tempdb"